# REQUIRED || REQUIRED HTML5 Forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms, client-side-validation, required

I have arrived to a situation that if only one of the two required fields in the form are filled then it should submit the form. Unfortunately, if i put `required` on both the fields it would wait for both of them to be filled in. Can this work without using JS? I know it is nearly impossible while not knowing any of the hidden features regarding it?

Comment: No. You need JS for that complexity of validation. You can tie into the HTML 5 validation API though.

Comment: its seems to be impossible without javascript. However, now i am also interested in knowing

Comment: @ Mohammad: Just ticking the box, here, but you're *also* validating server-side, right?

Comment: What's with the downvote on the question? This is a good question, one of the few we see these days.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this work without using JS?

No, you need JavaScript to do that validation client-side.

Answer (score 0):

The solution requires JS, but is easy - simply toggle the `.required` property of the elements based on whether either of them has a value:

```js
var t1 = document.getElementById('test1');
var t2 = document.getElementById('test2');

function toggleRequired() {
    t2.required = (t1.value.trim() === '');
    t1.required = (t2.value.trim() === '');
}

t1.addEventListener('change', toggleRequired, false);
t2.addEventListener('change', toggleRequired, false);
```

```html
<form>
    <input name="test1" id="test1" required />
    <br/>
    <input name="test2" id="test2" required />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: what if both of them had a value?

Comment: then both `required` properties will be set to false, but as they both have a value it doesn't matter, since the desired result has been achieved.

Comment: sure, because it's registered on the `onchange` event.  By all means change that, but in any event (no pun intended) that event _should_ be fired any time focus leaves the control and before the `submit` button gets pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also put it into one div. It did worked for me.

```
<form>
  <div class=question>
    <input id="field1_1" name="field1" required>
    <input id="field1_2" name="field1" required>
    <input type="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```